# Symfony2, FOSUserBundle - fetching userdata doesn't close connection

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

The FOSUserBundle is fetching userdata on every request.

The problem is that everytime after fetching data it leaves the mysql connection open.
Doctrine doesn't close the connection.
So after a while I get like 1000+ open mysql connections.

Comment: Is there sample code you can add to show what you're trying?

Comment: just a clean install symfony 2 with fosuserbundle. made a user and after login: everytime loading a new page it does a query on the database to fetch userdata.

Comment: That is correct bahaivor! If you disable some user it will be logged out on new page load for example.

Comment: If a user keeps refreshing a page 1000 times, then I'll get 1000 mysql connections. This can't be right, right? Is there a way to fix this?